# A Common Handler for all Ajax Responses

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have more than a dozen ajax calls in the page, all with different purposes. I wanted to know if I can write a function which can catch any ajax call's response on the page. If the response is a text, "Catch me", the function prevents default ajax success function and alerts "Caught"; if not, it follows the default success function.

Basically, can I write a function that catches all ajax calls on the page and checks their response text.

A tedious way would be to edit each ajax call, but I'm trying to avoid that.

Comment: You could create one handler callback, but it depends on the structure of your existing ones. You are almost certainly going to need to refactor your existing code to accommodate a common handler.  We can't help much without seeing specific code.

Comment: Yes, this is possible. Check out the jQuery documentation on Ajax events.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the [Global AJAX Event Handlers](http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/global-ajax-event-handlers/) in jQuery. The page says:

> *These methods register handlers to be called when certain events, such
>   as initialization or completion, **take place for any AJAX request on
>   the page**. The global events are fired on each AJAX request **if the
>   global property in jQuery.ajaxSetup() is true, which it is by default**.
>   Note: Global events are never fired for cross-domain script or JSONP
>   requests, regardless of the value of global.*

So your code should simply look like this (I used a random selector, it's not necessary to use "body"):

```
$("body").ajaxComplete(function(e, xhr, settings){ alert(xhr.responseText); });​​​​​​​
```

Answer (score 1):

I see that you're trying to create global handler which executes on the response, just **before** success event. Next, based on some condition, breaks the default behavior (by displaying alert in your case), or passes the flow further (to the custom success event, as each your ajax call can have different logic to run on success).

To do so you should modify the ajax handler provided by jQuery a bit:

```
var ns = {};
(function(ctx) {
    ctx.ajax = function(options, callback){
        var defaults = {
            success: function (data) {
                if (data != "Catch me") {
                    callback(data);
                } else {
                    alert("Catched");
                }
            }
        };
        $.extend(options, defaults);
        $.ajax(options);
    };   
})(ns);
```

The ajax call should be invoked just like below:

```
ns.ajax(options, function (data) {
    alert("success, inside callback");
});
```